# How to build project with previous .NET Framework?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I wrote a project using .NET Framework 4.6.2. After reinstalling OS Windows and installing the new Visual Studio IDE the project does not launch.

It requires the previous framework, because the current is newest. I tried to change .NET framework in properties of solution. But there is only current version. Then I tried to install required version of framework, it invoke an error like as: you have already installed Framework the latest version.

So, I am in deadlock. How to build project?

I get this error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dkw1i.png)

Comment: Can you update the project to use the most recent version?

Comment: How to do that? I have dependencies from Nuget

Comment: .NET Framwork versioning is complicated, but if you get that error message, it should mean your current installed version (4.6.2) is completely compatible with the version you tried to install. (There are very minor regressions, but they are hard to encounter.) When you say "does not launch", what exactly happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a project you can specify target framework

[image]